# Fully packaged container for montoring

Tags: monitoring

I am looking for a container that can easily be used for deploying a monitoring solution.

Mainly it want: influxdb, grafana and collectd but I do not want to build the container myself, prefering to rely on someone that does and keep updating it.

Comment: So what shall it be able to monitor? And what containers shall it use? Also note I removed "Best" from the title, as "best" is almost always subjective (and be assured, we usually don't recommend "worst" :)

Comment: Are you specifically wanting collectd for the monitoring backend?  If not, that opens you up to a lot of other possibilities (both Prometheus and  Netdata have pre-built Docker containers on the Docker Hub for example).